# Ubuntu 22.04 LTS says no bluetooth found plug in a dongle to use bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, asus, .desktop, lts, 22.04

I have currently clean installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop stable build which was released on April 21/04/2022,on my Asus K55VJ 3rd gen Corei5,GT 635 M with 2GB of VRAM,8GB RAM...Now when i go to the bluetooth menu through settings , I get a error saying No bluetooth found plugin a dongle to use bluetooth.
Pls suggest me solution with some images attached so that i can rectify, i am not a computer guy and I am new to ubuntu so answer accordingly thnk u..

[See i have in build bluetooth in this device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pyp1M.png)

[The service is running but no controller is availaible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4ysK.png)

[In rfkill list it is not showing the bluetooth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpylL.png)

[This the last image of settings where i cant toggle the bluetooth on or off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gwh4p.png)
[output of lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb; dmesg | grep -i blue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tNxY.png)

what could be the problem ???

Comment: Please don't post duplicates [Ubuntu 22.10 doesn't recognises bluetooth of Asus K55vj laptop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403652/ubuntu-22-10-doesnt-recognises-bluetooth-of-asus-k55vj-laptop)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb; dmesg | grep -i blue` terminal command.

Comment: added the output see by urself i cant understand what it says u may be able to decode it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Patch file not found ar3k/AthrBT\_0x31010000.dfu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403934/patch-file-not-found-ar3k-athrbt-0x31010000-dfu)

Answer (score 2):

Check the result for this:

```
sudo dmesg |grep -i bluetooth
```

My case was identical to yours, and I was giving this error in the result:

```
[    3.935429] Bluetooth: Patch file not found ar3k/AthrBT_0x11020000.dfu
```

And the solution was to follow [zxcde's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1404004/618353) to [Patch file not found ar3k/AthrBT_0x31010000.dfu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403934/patch-file-not-found-ar3k-athrbt-0x31010000-dfu):

> You can try my solution:
>
> 1. Download `linux-firmware_1.201.tar.xz` from http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.201.tar.xz
>    (you can visit https://packages.ubuntu.com/impish/linux-firmware for
>    more details).
> 2. Extract `linux-firmware_1.201.tar.xz` and copy the `ar3k` folder into `/lib/firmware`.
> 3. Restart your computer.

Comment: zYes mine is also saying 293998] Bluetooth: Patch file not found ar3k/AthrBT_0x01020200.dfu
and i followed ur site but after downloading the said file i cant find the /lib/firmware folder to copy the atk file can u help me with that ??

Comment: Much Much thnx buddy figured out how to copy the req file to the destination folder and it worked many many thnx the solutions...

Comment: I'm glad it worked! If anyone else has the same doubt as our friend had, it is necessary to have root privileges to modify the system folders, so it can be done via terminal or opening nautilus via sudo.

Comment: sudo dmesg |grep -i bluetooth doesnt give any output for me... I'm pretty sure that my laptop has bluetooth and I never needed any "dongle"