# Bluetooth doesn't work on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: drivers, apt, gnome, bluetooth, 22.04

I could use the Bluetooth which is integrated on-board on Ubuntu version 21.04, but I cannot make it on 22.04 in no way. If it worked on the previous version, it should work on the new version, right?

```
$ lspci -vvnn | grep -A 9 Network
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0036] (rev 01)
    DeviceName: WLAN
    Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [11ad:1823]
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 21
    IOMMU group: 11
    Region 0: Memory at a1100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=512K]
    Expansion ROM at a1180000 [disabled] [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
```

Comment: You can take a look at this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403817/i-cant-turn-on-bluetooth-in-ubuntu-22-04-lts

Comment: Edit your question and add the output from this `lspci -vvnn | grep -A 9 Network` command please.

Comment: Apparently this is a common error with Qualcomm bluetooth on 22.04.

Comment: i added the codes. So, won't i be able to work it?

Answer (score 3):

At last I solved the problem through downloading & moving the `ar3k` folder to `/lib/firmware`. Whoever has the same problem, can follow [Sujit's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1404683/618353) to this question: [I can't turn on Bluetooth in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403817/i-cant-turn-on-bluetooth-in-ubuntu-22-04-lts)

> So I finally found the fix for this.
>
> Source: [Nilson Oliveira's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1404258/1119550) to [Ubuntu 22.04 LTS says no bluetooth found plug in a dongle to use bluetooth](https://askubuntu.com/q/1403696/618353)
>
> > Check the result for this:
> >
> > ```sh
> > sudo dmesg |grep -i bluetooth
> > ```
> >
> > My case was identical to yours, and I was giving this error in the result:
> >
> > ```
> > [    3.935429] Bluetooth: Patch file not found ar3k/AthrBT_0x11020000.dfu
> > ```
> >
> > And the solution was to follow [zxcde's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1404004/618353) to [Patch file not
> > found ar3k/AthrBT_0x31010000.dfu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403934/patch-file-not-found-ar3k-athrbt-0x31010000-dfu):
> >
> > > You can try my solution:
> > >
> > > 1. Download `linux-firmware_1.201.tar.xz` from http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.201.tar.xz
> > >    (you can visit https://packages.ubuntu.com/impish/linux-firmware for
> > >    more details).
> > > 2. Extract `linux-firmware_1.201.tar.xz` and copy the `ar3k` folder into `/lib/firmware`.
> > > 3. Restart your computer.
>
> 1. If you get the output in the blockquote above, download `linux-firmware_1.201.tar.xz` from
>    [here](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/).
> 2. Extract it and go to the folder as shown below:
>
>    [image: extracted folder]
> 3. Copy the folder `ar3k` to `/lib/firmware`. You can also use the following command:
>
>    ```sh
>    sudo cp -R ar3k /lib/firmware
>    ```
>
>    **Note:** Make sure you open the terminal within the extracted folder.
> 4. Restart your PC and you should be able to use Bluetooth again.