# Why can I not connect devices to bluetooth since switching from Windows to ubuntu

Tags: bluetooth

So I have a double boot system (Windows 10 and Ubuntu 22.04). When I run my windows system I'm perfectly able to run my Bluetooth keyboard and speakers without any problem.
On Ubuntu however it keeps telling me to plug in a "dongle to use bluetooth" even though I am using one for Windows and it works there.

I already tried fixing this issue by trying to follow this answer here: [Ubuntu 22.04 LTS says no bluetooth found plug in a dongle to use bluetooth](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403696/ubuntu-22-04-lts-says-no-bluetooth-found-plug-in-a-dongle-to-use-bluetooth/1416610#1416610)
I was able to download the file that is mentioned there but was not able to copy the ar3k folder into the /lib/firmware for numerous reasons.

Being an absolute linux beginner I did not know how to do that. (What was the command again, can anyone refresh my mind? It was something that involved '-R' somewhere)

I eventually found the correct command but I cannot seem to find it again and the terminal said that I don't have permission to do that.

Can people tell me how to get my bluetooth working another way, the permission to copy this ar3k folder and the command that I forgot?

Thanks

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb; dmesg | grep -i blue` terminal command.

Comment: Without knowing what is the BT hardware all your efforts are useless. There is no generic BT solution.

Comment: The above notwithstanding, something you should know is that when dual-booting with Windows disabling its Fast Startup feature is a must. One of its side effects is hijacking some devices. So, disable it and shutdown Windows. Boot Ubuntu and try again.